# Possibility of finding a such function?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Is it possible to find a continuous function $f$: $[0,1]$ $\rightarrow$ {$0,1$} that is onto?

My thoughts: I know if $A$ & $B$ are two subsets of a top. space $X$ and if there exists a continuous function $f$: $X$ $\rightarrow [0,1]$ s.t $f(A)=${0} & $f(B)=${1}, we say $A$ & $B$ can be a separated by a continuous function $f$.

But the problem is $[0,1]$ is connected and hence can't find a separation of it.Is it possible to find such a function?.

Alternatively, I know Urysohn lemma and the definition of a completely regular space(which are somewhat related to this but not quite). Any thoughts?

Comment: Continuous functions preserve both connected-ness and compact-ness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is onto then $f^{-1}(0)$ and $f^{-1}(1)$ are disjoint closed non-empty subsets of $[0,1]$ which contradicts connectedness of $[0,1]$. Hence such a function does not exist.

Comment: Why would the two disjoint closed sets violate the connectedness of $[0,1]$?

Comment: @SL_MathGuy There (relative) complements in $[0,1]$ are non-empty disjoint open sets whose union is $[0,1]$ and this is a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. If $X,Y$ are topological spaces with $X$ connected and $f: X\to Y$ is continuous, then $f(X)\subset Y$ is connected. Since $\{0,1\}$ (with discrete topology) is disconnected, there exists no such surjective $f$

Comment: Ohh..Why this simple thing didn't come to my mind.. Anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Proposition**: let $X$ be a topological space, then TFAE:

1. $X$ is connected.
2. If $O \subseteq X$ is clopen (closed and open), $O=\emptyset$ or $O=X$.
3. Every continuous $f:X \to \{0,1\}$ (the two point set in the discrete topology) is constant.

**Proof**: $1 \implies 2$: If $O$ were clopen and not empty and not equal to $X$, $\{O, X\setminus O\}$ would be a disconnection of $X$ (both sets are open, non-empty and trivially disjoint), contradiction.

$2\implies 3$: If $f: X \to \{0,1\}$ is continuous, then $f^{-1}[\{0\}]$ is clopen as the inverse image of a clopen set, so is empty (and $f \equiv 1$) or $X$ (and $f \equiv 0$).

$3 \implies 1$: Suppose $X= U \cup V$ were a disconnection of $X$. Then the function $f$ sending all points of $U$ to $0$ and all points of $V$ to $1$ is well-defined ($U$ and $V$ are disjoint) and continuous (pasting lemma using that $U,V$ are open and constant maps are continuous) and non-constant (both sets are non-empty). This contradiction shows $X$ is connected.

As $[0,1]$ is connected, no such map as you look for exists.